# Identify feature tool auto open form is not working in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, identify

I am using QGIS 2.14, and using the 'Identify Features' tool.

I have the 'Auto open form' checked, I am zoomed in so I can identify a single feature easily, I have the layer selected, I have the layer in editing mode, and the 'Mode' set to 'Current layer'. 
The layer is an spatialite offline file from a PostGIS database.

In the past the form would open automatically and I could edit the attributes of the feature.

This has now stopped working for me. I can click into the 'Identify results' dock and then 'Edit form feature' to manually open the form.

Can anyone tell me why the form won't open for me automatically?

Comment: u sure there are no overlaid duplicate features in your layer?

Comment: @MykolaKozyr - Hi Mykola, perhaps you could add your comment as an answer, then I can mark it as answered. This question was raised in a workshop I was at recently and so I think it may be quite a common question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mykola Kozyr commented;

If there are duplicate, or overlapping features in a layer, then the `Form` will not open when the `Identify feature` tool is used.

Instead the 'Identify results' window will open. This will list the features that are present at the co-ordinates where the identify tool was clicked.

To open the form right-click on one of the features and select `Edit feature form`

[image]

Comment: Note: Answering own question in an attempt to remove it from the unanswered queue. But credit to Mykola Kozyr - will delete my answer if he posts an answer for me to accept - as requested in comments of OP.